# Conditionally change the output of data-sizes with Lazysizes RIaS plugin

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I'm working on a site that uses Cloudinary and the [LazySizes RIaS](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/tree/gh-pages/plugins/rias) plugin and for the most part it works fine.

I have my config like this:

```
window.lazySizesConfig = window.lazySizesConfig || {};
window.lazySizesConfig.rias = window.lazySizesConfig.rias || {
prefix: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/user/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,c_scale/w_{width}/',
absUrl: true
}
```

Most of the images I want to be full width of the column and they're fine. But some of the source images aren't that wide and I don't want them to be full width.

But LazySizes will set the same `sizes` value on all of the images which is equal to the width of the column which means that some get upscaled and stretched.

Does anyone know of a way, either with a `data` attribute in the markup or a conditional in the js config, which will allow me to tell LazySizes to not apply the default `sizes` output for certain images?

It seems if I try and use any value other that `auto` for `data-sizes` that LazySizes will fail to run for that image.

I thought I could maybe use the example you used for `data-format` which does output different values in the `srcset` but the `sizes` still equals the width of the column.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the answer to my particular situation was to add `style:max-width: XXpx` to the `img` tag if the width of the image was smaller than the `max-width` of the parent.